Is My Income Halal (Bing Reward)
"Bing Rewards is a program where users earn points by searching on the Bing search engine and completing tasks, which can then be redeemed for rewards like gift cards. The program allows up to five accounts per household, but I am the only one in my household who uses Bing. I created and use all five accounts myself to earn more rewards, as my family does not use the platform. Additionally, I am considering creating more than five accounts and doing the tasks (such as searches) to earn even more points. Is it permissible in Islam to create and use these multiple accounts for the purpose of earning more rewards, even if it might go against the platform’s intended use?"
